# Nativescript Angular compiling error "mergeDexDebug"

Tags: nativescript, angular-nativescript

I am using nativescript v6.4 and angular v8.2 and in project i have install 4-5 plugin and it work fine but after installing one more plugin i.e nativescript-firebase-plugin i got this error when compiling the project.

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 132015 > 65536 ; # fields: 77460 > 65536)

Answer (score 3):

Did you go through the [documentation](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase#known-issues-on-android) of Firebase Plugin?

> Adding `multiDexEnabled true` to your `app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle` should solve the issue